# Convert Python to Groovy - Nested JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary, groovy

I am working on implementing a workflow using Nextflow. Nextflow uses groovy as it's base language and then each process can use any programming language independently. I am essentially a Python programmer, so the code I've written is in Python. And am having a little trouble converting the language.

```py
data = {
    "a" : "A",
    "b" : "B",
    "c" : {
        "somename":{
            "z" : "Z",
            "y" : "Y",
            "params" :{
                "minimum": "3000",
                "ignore": "60",
                "maximum_A": "2500",
                "maximum_B": "500"
            }
        },

        "somename2":{
            "z" : "Z",
            "y" : "Y",
            "params" :{
                "minimum": "3000",
                "ignore": "60",
                "maximum_A": "2500",
                "maximum_B": "500"
            }
        }
    }
}

CNS_PARAM_LIST = []
my_dict = {}

for each in data["c"]:
    for k, v in data["c"][each].get('params', {}).items():
        CNS_PARAM_LIST.extend([k, str(v)])
    my_dict[each] = CNS_PARAM_LIST

print(my_dict)
```

Basically, I have a JSON (data) and I need to make a dictionary from some nested fields. The output for the above code is:

```
{'somename': ['minimum', '3000', 'ignore', '60', 'maximum_A', '2500', 'maximum_B', '500', 'minimum', '3000', 'ignore', '60', 'maximum_A', '2500', 'maximum_B', '500'], 'somename2': ['minimum', '3000', 'ignore', '60', 'maximum_A', '2500', 'maximum_B', '500', 'minimum', '3000', 'ignore', '60', 'maximum_A', '2500', 'maximum_B', '500']}
```

Simply, make `somename` and `somename2` the keys, and make `params` the values.

Any groovy coder that could crack this in 1/100th the time I can? I'm sure there is also some way to make this code more efficient, any ideas are welcome!

Comment: More effiecient than what?  Please provide the Groovy code you have tried so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just misspelled when duplicated keys for each somename

the first diff in groovy is how to declare a map (dictionary in python)

```
my_dict = [:]
```

more about groovy collections you can find here: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html

the code for your case:

```
def data = [
    "a" : "A",
    "b" : "B",
    "c" : [
        "somename":[
            "z" : "Z",
            "y" : "Y",
            "params" :[
                "minimum": "3000",
                "ignore": "60",
                "maximum_A": "2500",
                "maximum_B": "500"
            ]
        ],

        "somename2":[
            "z" : "Z",
            "y" : "Y",
            "params" :[
                "minimum": "3000",
                "ignore": "60",
                "maximum_A": "2500",
                "maximum_B": "500"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
def my_dict = data.c.collectEntries{k,v-> [k,v.params]  }

println my_dict
//if you want to print it as json:
println groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(my_dict)
```

i'm using [collectEntries](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#collectEntries(groovy.lang.Closure)) method on Map object

you could find other methods for Map in GDK documentation: [groovy Map](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html) just google [gdk map](https://www.google.com/search?q=gdk+map)

as soon as groovy Map extends java Map check main methods in javadoc: [java Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: Thank you sir, crisp and efficient!